# PHPMyAdmin - Total record count varies

Tags: sql, count, phpmyadmin

I am running a request on a table of records with phpmyadmin, and the results count varies. For example, when showing the results it says "Showing records 1 - (~180,234 )".
This number changes each time I refresh, and no data is being added or removed.
When I do a SQL request for the record, the result stays the same. Is this an issue with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: What storage engine are you using? Can you drop in your schema for that table?

Comment: The engin I am using is MyISAM. I can't put the schema on as it is something which i'm not allowed to share unfortunately.

Comment: Are you certain the engine is not InnoDB for that specific table?  Also, does this issue affect all tables in the database, or only certain ones?

Comment: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` and then check the engine at the end of the returned create string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For InnoDB tables, from phpMyAdmin's FAQ:

> phpMyAdmin uses a quick method to get
>   the row count, and this method only
>   returns an approximate count in the
>   case of InnoDB tables. See
>   $cfg['MaxExactCount'] for a way to
>   modify those results, but this could
>   have a serious impact on performance.

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=maxexactcount#cfg_MaxExactCount

Answer (score 1):

If you mouse over the "rows" column heading it says *"May be approximate"*

[image]

It's because some types of tables only show an approximate count. I would add that it's also *not always updated*, so for example if you empty the table it can be showing a previous high number (so not even approximately correct!)

The above screenshot also says *"Click on the number to get the exact count"*. This is not working for me, but one way to get an exact count for one or all tables (as a one-off refresh at least), is to tell phpMyAdmin to 'analyze' the table(s) like this:

[image]