# Make phpMyAdmin show exact number of records for InnoDB tables?

Tags: phpmyadmin, innodb

Is there any way to make phpMyAdmin show exact number of records for InnoDB tables?

I know why InnoDB has *different* number of records based on interpretation because it's a transactional engine but SQLBuddy is showing the exact number of records for InnoDB tables so I think there is a way for phpMyAdmin to do the same.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just found the answer on this thread: [PHPMyAdmin - Total record count varies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993213/phpmyadmin-total-record-count-varies)

Seems adding a configuration parameter in config.inc.php does the trick: http://www.kavoir.com/2012/07/make-phpmyadmin-show-exact-number-of-records-for-innodb-tables.html

Just add this line in config.inc.php:

```
$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 2000000;
```

So that any InnoDB table with less than 2000000 rows will have an exact number of rows displayed.

Make this number large enough and all InnoDB tables in your database will have an exact number of rows on phpMyAdmin database page.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the reply you referenced, this could be performance issue (i have not tested if it really does). 
There is quick workaround, number of rows could be seen if you export your table to spreadsheet (select table, go to export and then export it in one format that you could open on your machine), and see exact nuber of rows there.