# Large (1G) MySQL db taking 30 hours to import into WAMP, plus Null errors

Tags: mysql, wamp

I've been working on this for days, pretty frustrated.

Have a Magento database, about 1Gb with 3MM records - need to make a backup and import it onto my local machine.  Local machine is running WAMP on a brand new gaming rig specs with 16 Gb RAM).  Exported the db fine using PHPMyAdmin into a .sql file.

Saw BigDump was highly recommended to import a large db.  Also find a link that says it's recommended for the syntax to `include column names in every INSERT statement`  Done.  ( http://www.atomicsmash.co.uk/blog/import-large-sql-databases/  )

Start importing.  Hours go by (around 3-4).  Get an error:  `Page unavailable, or wrong url!` More searching, try suggestions ( mostly here: http://www.sitehostingtalk.com/f16/bigdump-error-page-unavailable-wrong-url-56939/ ) to drop the `$linespersession` to 500 and add a `$delaypersession` of 300.  Run again, more hours, same error.

I then re-exported the db into two .sql dumps (one that held all the large tables with over 100K records), repeat, same error.  So I quit using Bigdump.

Next up was the command line!  Using Console2 I ran `source mydump.sql`.  **30 hours** go by.  Then an error:

`ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'`

More searching, really varied explanations.  I tried with the split files from before - run it again, same error.

I can't figure out what would cause both of these errors.  I know that I got the same error on two different exports.  I know there are a few tables that are between 1-300,000 rows.  I also don't think 30 hours is normal (on a screaming fast machine) for an import of only a 1Gb but I could be wrong.

What other options should I try?  Is it the format of the export?  Should it be compressed or not?  Is there a faster way of importing?  Any way of making this go faster?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to some searching and @Bill Karwin suggestion here's where I'm at:

- Grabbed a new mysqldump using ssh and downloaded it.
- Imported the database 10 different times.  Each time was MUCH faster (5-10 mins) so that fixed the ridiculous import time.

  - used command line, `>source dump.sql`
- However, each import from that same dump.sql file has a different number of records.  Of the 3 million records they differ by between 600 and 200,000 records.  One of the imports has 12,000 MORE records than the original.  I've tried with and without setting the `foreign_key_checks = 0;`  I tried running the same query multiple times with exactly the same settings.  Every time the number of rows are different.

I'm also getting these errors now:

`ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'time_zone' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'foreign_key_checks' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'unique_checks' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'sql_notes' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'`

Doesn't seem like these are that important from what I read.  There are other warnings but I can't seem to determine what they are.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** *Solution removed here and listed below as a separate post*

**References:**

https://serverfault.com/questions/244725/how-to-is-mysqls-net-buffer-length-config-viewed-and-reset

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_buffer_length

[Make phpMyAdmin show exact number of records for InnoDB tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682777/make-phpmyadmin-show-exact-number-of-records-for-innodb-tables)

[Export a large MySQL table as multiple smaller files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112720/mysql-large-table-export)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-max-allowed-packet-is-larger-in-mysqldump-than-mysqld-in-my-cnf

Comment: You either run against timeout or just didn't set some missing variables. But you'd be better off importing with native mysql software than through a webbrowser..

Comment: @native mysql software - I agree, though 30+ hrs each attempt is killing me.

Comment: Do not include the resolution in the question. But feel free to add an answer.

Comment: I've seen a lot of solutions edited back into the question - is that a new policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not a normal restore time, unless you're running MySQL on a 15 year old computer or you're trying to write the database to a shared volume over a very slow network. I can import a data dump of about that size in about 45 minutes, even on an x-small EC2 instance.

The error about setting variables to NULL appears to be a limitation of BigDump. It's mentioned in the [BigDump FAQ](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/faqs/). I have never seen those errors from restoring a dump file with the command-line client.

So here are some recommendations:

- Make sure your local MySQL data directory is on a locally-attached drive -- not a network drive.
- Use the `mysql` command-line client, not phpMyAdmin or BigDump.

  ```
  mysql> source mydump.sql
  ```
- Dump files are mostly a long list of INSERT statements, you can read [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html) for tips on speeding up INSERT. Be sure to read the sub-pages it links to.
- For example, when you export the database, check the radiobutton for "insert multiple rows in every INSERT statement" (this is incompatible with BigDump, but better for performance when you use `source` in the mysql client).
- Durability settings are recommended for production use, but they come with some performance penalties. It sounds like you're just trying to get a development instance running, so reducing the durability may be worthwhile, at least while you do your import. A good summary of reducing durability is found in MySQL Community Manager Morgan Tocker's blog: [Reducing MySQL durability for testing](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/11/04/reducing-mysql-durability-for-testing.html).

---

Re your new questions and errors:

A lot of people report similar errors when importing a large dump file created by phpMyAdmin or Drupal or other tools.

The most likely cause is that you have some data in the dump file that is larger than `max_allowed_packet`. This MySQL config setting is the largest size for an individual SQL statement or an individual row of data. When you exceed this in an individual SQL statement, the server aborts that SQL statement, and closes your connection. The mysql client tries to reconnect automatically and resume sourcing the dump file, but there are two side-effects:

- Some of your rows of data failed to load.
- The session variables that preserve `@time_zone` and other settings during the import are lost, because they are scoped to the session. When the reconnect happens, you get a new session.

The fix is to increase your `max_allowed_packet`. The default level is 4MB on MySQL 5.6, and only 1MB on earlier versions. You can find out what your current value for this config is:

```
mysql> SELECT @@max_allowed_packet;
+----------------------+
| @@max_allowed_packet |
+----------------------+
|              4194304 |
+----------------------+
```

You can increase it as high as 1GB:

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet = 1024*1024*1024;
```

Then try the import again:

```
mysql> source mydump.sql
```

Also, if you're measuring the size of the tables with a command like `SHOW TABLE STATUS` or a query against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, you should know that the `TABLE_ROWS` count is only an *estimate* -- it can be pretty far off, like +/- 10% (or more) of the actual number of rows of the table. The number reported is even likely to change from time to time, even if you haven't changed any data in the table. The only true way to count rows in a table is with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable`.

Comment: Thank you!  I made an edit - those links are great, but now every time I'm importing the .sql file there are a different number of records (see my edit).  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

For anyone who wanted a step by step:

- Using PuTTY, grab a mysql dump of the database (don't include everything to the right of the > and replace all capitals with the appropriate info)

`> mysqldump -uUSERNAME -p DATABASENAME > DATABASE_DUMP_FILE_NAME.sql`

- You'll get a password prompt, type it in, hit enter.  Wait till you get a prompt again.  If you're using an FTP client go to the root of your host and you should see your file there, download it.
- Locally get a mysql prompt by navigating to where your mysql.exe file is (there's a few ways of doing this, this is one of them) and typing:

`> mysql.exe -use NEW_DATABASE -u USERNAME`

- Now you're in the mysql prompt.  Turn on warnings...just in case

`mysql > \W;`

- Increase the max_allowed_packet to a true Gig.  I've seen references to also changing the net_buffer_length but after 5.1.31 it doesn't seem to be changed (link at bottom)

`mysql > SET global max_allowed_packet = 1024*1024*1024;`

- Now import your sql file

`mysql > source C:\path\to\DATABASE_DUMP_FILE_NAME.sql`

If you want to check if all of the records imported you could either type `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable` OR

- Go to C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php
- At the bottom before the `?>` add:

`/* Show the exact count of each row */`

`$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 2000000;`

- This is only recommended for a development platform - but really handy when you have to scan a bunch of tables / databases.  Will probably slow down the works with large sets.