# Random row number in PMA (localhost)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know it sounds strange but my PMA can not tell the exact number of rows inside a table. I double checked and nothing uses the that table (nor the database).

[at this point http://orosznyet.com/screencast/20130526074812960.jpeg](http://orosznyet.com/screencast/20130526074812960.jpeg)

279 should be constant but it changes on every reload randomly. I tried to defrag, optimize, check and FLUSH the table but nothing helps.

The datas are stored and can be accessed with no problem. The problem is that the pagination is based on this number and it's hard to use PMA when a page suddenly disappears. + I can not trust the row number anymore.

I never experienced issue like this.
PMA version: 4.0.0

Comment: Run a separate `COUNT()` query to get the real number of rows. The given linenumbers in PMA are just estimates, which can vary.

Comment: I have never experienced this problem. I mean this function worked pretty well in all previous versions. +The tables contains about few hundred rows, not ten thousands or more.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4993213/1169798