# MySQL Static Database - Why are the row counts fluctuating so much

Tags: mysql, rowcount

MySQL 5.1
About 50 million records in 53 tables.
A static database - nothing is written to it.

Every time I refresh phpMyAdmin - the total row count for all tables fluctuates.
Up or down - by as much as couple of hundred thousand rows 0_0

No caching going on in my browser.
I tried a few different browsers.
Same database copy on my local machine - and it DOES NOT fluctuate with refresh.

- **Why are the row counts fluctuating so much?**
- **What could be the cause?**
- **Could this be a big problem?**

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPMyAdmin - Total record count varies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993213/phpmyadmin-total-record-count-varies)

Answer (score 1):

The row count for an InnoDB table is approximate.  To get the exact row count of a table with transactional integrity would require going through the table.  Instead, you are seeing an approximation that is derived from some random probes.

I have seen that number be off by as much as a factor of two -- either direction.

There is no real 'problem'.  That's life.